# NSAppTransportSecurity UIWebView issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9, nsurlrequest

I have these lines in my info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mysebserver.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

So it works perfect with my API calls.

In my view controller I have UIWebView that tries to display web content:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.webSiteUrlSting] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

[self.theWebView loadRequest:request];
```

on iOS7 and iOS8 it works great, but on iOS9 it shows an error after invocation UIWebView delegate `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

The delegate method contain error instance that looks like this:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbaa253ba20 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=requestedwebsite.com,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=requestedwebsite.com}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=requestedwebsite.com,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=requestedwebsite.com,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.}

My question is how to keep my API requests work and make UIWebView work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this exception in your `NSAppTransportSecurity` dict:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```