# App transport security issue in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, ios9

I am trying to display http url in webview and I get below ATS error.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I have added **NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads** exception in info.plist . But still I get error.

NOTE: Unfortunately I can't disable the ATS in my app as all the webservices consumed in application are TLS1.2 with  forward secrecy.

Is there any solution which I can bypass ATS in webview?

Looking forward to any advices on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to allow the web view to access *anything*, so a list of exception domains where you allow insecure access is not going to work.

You can turn the usual ATS "allow everything" or "opt-out for just this" exceptions on its head by allowing arbitrary loads, but then specifying your servers as exceptions, as described in **"Using ATS For Your Servers and Allowing Insecure Connections Elsewhere"** [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

Essentially you allow arbitrary loads, but then add your own domains as exceptions. Access to those domains will then be subject to the ATS rules .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the domain to your plist as an exception, here is an example of how to do it:

[image]

Comment: I have already added it as exception.                                                       <dict>
  <key>stackoverflow.com</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSIncludeSubdomains</key>
   <true/>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
 </dict>

Comment: but what if @Vijay will need to open other domains via WebView too, for example tap on link that redirect to other website?

Comment: can you recheck my answer/question I've added? Because that's not one solution.

Comment: If you don't know what domains you want to use then add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to the plist and set it to true

Answer (score 0):

You can missing add information into file Info.plist
[image: image with information]

Answer (score 0):

I have this answer on my question here:

[NSAppTransportSecurity UIWebView issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218894/nsapptransportsecurity-uiwebview-issue)

it helped to me, but I am not sure if that's only one solution.